# grabbing the selected data from the Jcombo

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

Trying to save the users selection into a string to use further in the code. but I'm unsuccessful in retrieving the data that the users selects. not to sure if I'm doing it wrong or right, or how to do it to be honest because i feel as if I'm doing it wrong. the code is commented out near the bottom of the script. and is

```
 //String stationS = (String)station.getSelectedItem();
```

and the rest of the code is this just incase for referencing on how i create a jcombobox

```
import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.Dialog.ModalityType;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;

public class TouchOn extends JDialog {
private JPanel mainPanel;

public ArrayList Reader(String Txtfile) {
    try {

    ArrayList<String> Trains = new ArrayList<String>();
    int count = 0;
    String testing = "";
    File file = new File(Txtfile);
    FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
    StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
    String line;
    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) 
    {
        stringBuffer.append(line);
        count += count;
        if(!line.contains("*")){
            Trains.add(line + "\n");
        }
        stringBuffer.append("\n");



    }
    fileReader.close();
    //Arrays.asList(Trains).stream().forEach(s -> System.out.println(s));
    return Trains;
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
//return toString();
return null;




 }


public TouchOn()
{
    setPanels();

    setModalityType(ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL);
    setSize(400, 300);
    setVisible(true);
}
public void setPanels()
{
    mainPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 2));
    JPanel containerPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1));
    JLabel startDay = new JLabel("Day:");
    JTextField sDay = new JTextField();

    JLabel startMonth = new JLabel("Month:");
    JTextField sMonth = new JTextField();

    JLabel startYear = new JLabel("Year:");
    JTextField sYear = new JTextField("2015");
    String trainline;
    String checked = "";

    JLabel touchOnTimehr = new JLabel("Time Hour: ");
    JLabel touchOnTimem = new JLabel("Time Minute:");
    JLabel station = new JLabel("Station: ");


    JTextField touchOnTimeFieldhour = new JTextField();
    JTextField touchOnTimeFieldminute = new JTextField();

    JPanel lowerPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
    ArrayList<String> stations = Reader("TrainLines.txt");
    JComboBox<String> cb = new JComboBox<>(stations.toArray(new String[stations.size()]));
    JRadioButton belgrave = new JRadioButton("Belgrave Line");      
    JRadioButton glenwaverly = new JRadioButton("Glen Waverly Line");
    ButtonGroup bG = new ButtonGroup();
    JButton apply = new JButton("Touch on");
    JButton cancel = new JButton("Cancel");
    cancel.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            dispose();
        }
    });
    apply.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {

            String timestamp = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").format(new Date());
            String day = sDay.getText();
            String month = sMonth.getText();
            String year = sYear.getText();
            String trainline = "";
            String hour = touchOnTimeFieldhour.getText();
            String minute = touchOnTimeFieldminute.getText();
            if(belgrave.isSelected()){
                trainline = belgrave.getText();
            }
            if(glenwaverly.isSelected()){
                trainline = glenwaverly.getText();
            }


            //String stationS = (String)station.getSelectedItem();

            // The code above is the one that doesnt im not to sure how it works 
            System.out.println(trainline);
        }
    });



    cb.setVisible(true);
    bG.add(belgrave);
    bG.add(glenwaverly);
    mainPanel.add(startDay);
    mainPanel.add(sDay);
    mainPanel.add(startMonth);
    mainPanel.add(sMonth);
    mainPanel.add(startYear);
    mainPanel.add(sYear);
    mainPanel.add(touchOnTimehr);
    mainPanel.add(touchOnTimeFieldhour);
    mainPanel.add(touchOnTimem);
    mainPanel.add(touchOnTimeFieldminute);
    mainPanel.add(belgrave);
    mainPanel.add(glenwaverly);
    mainPanel.add(station);
    mainPanel.add(new JLabel());
    mainPanel.add(cb);
    lowerPanel.add(apply);
    lowerPanel.add(cancel);
    touchOnTimeFieldhour.setSize(10,10);
    containerPanel.add(mainPanel);
    containerPanel.add(lowerPanel);

    add(containerPanel);
}



  }
```

Comment: `station` is a `JLabel`, not a combo box. You probably intended `cb` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMO the problem is, that you access local variables from inner class. Instead of adding actionListeners to the buttons, you should implement ActionLisntener into the TouchOn and override actionPerformed().

```
@override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ex){
    Object source = ex.getSource();
    if (source == apply){
        //your code here
    }
    if (source == cancel){
        //your code here
    }
```

In

```
//your code here
```

you can use references to your JRadioButtons

Comment: Yea, i have been meaning to change it, to no just be in ActionListeners how it is, because its a really bad habit for how i write. but to keep things the same i decided to 
`String stationS = (String)cb.getSelectedItem();`


and now I'm getting an error

`java.awt.IllegalComponentStateException: component must be showing on the screen to determine its location`

Comment: It would be very kind of you if you press an up-arrow if I've helped you, mate :)

Comment: hey, so sorry i feel asleep on the keyboard last night and completely forgot